# Working with dataframes in a list: Drop variables, add new ones

Tags: r, lapply, data-manipulation, data-management

Define a list *dats* with two dataframes, *df1* and *df2*

```
dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)),
    df2 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)))

> dats
$df1
  a  b
1 2 12
2 3 11
3 1 13

$df2
  a  b
1 3 13
2 2 11
3 1 12
```

I would like to drop variable *a* in each data frame.  Next I would like to add a variable with the id of each dataframe from an external dataframe, like:

```
ids <- data.frame(id=c("id1","id2"),df=c("df1","df2"))
> ids
  id  df
1 id1 df1
2 id2 df2
```

To drop unnecessary vars I tried this without luck:

```
> dats <- lapply(dats, function(x) assign(x, x[,c("b")]))  
> Error in assign(x, x[, c("b")]) : invalid first argument
```

Not sure how to add the id either.

I also tried, perhaps more appropriately:

```
> temp <- lapply(dats, function(x) subset(x[1], select=x[[1]]$b))
Error in x[[1]]$b : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What I find confusing is that `str(out[1])` returns a list, `str(out[[1]])` returns a dataframe.  I think that may have something to do with it.

Comment: feel free to rollback if you disagree w/ my edit. I like the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or try this: Extract your `ids` into a named vector that maps the data-frame name to the id:

```
df2id <- ids$id
names(df2id) <- ids$df

> df2id
df1 df2 
id1 id2 
Levels: id1 id2
```

Then use `mapply` to both (a) drop the `a` column from each data-frame, and (b) add the `id` column:

```
> mapply( function(d,x) cbind( subset(d, select = -a),
+                              id = x),
+         dats, df2id[ names(dats) ] ,
+         SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
$df1
   b  id
1 12 id1
2 11 id1
3 13 id1

$df2
   b  id
1 12 id2
2 11 id2
3 13 id2
```

Note that we are passing `df2id[ names(dats) ]` to the `mapply` -- this ensures that the data-frames in `df2id` are "aligned" with the data-frames in `dats`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this OK?

```
dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)),
    df2 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)))

ids <- data.frame(id=c("id1","id2"),df=c("df1","df2"))

# remove variable a
dats2 <- lapply(dats, function(x) x[,!names(x) == "a"])

# add id
for(i in 1:length(dats2)) {
  dats2[[i]] <- merge(dats2[[i]], ids$id[ids$df == names(dats2)[i]])
}

dats2

  $df1
     x   y
  1 11 id1
  2 12 id1
  3 13 id1

  $df2
     x   y
  1 11 id2
  2 12 id2
  3 13 id2
```

Comment: +1 Very concise.  In the real application I was trying to sort ids data frame so it had same order as dats2, then loop over one of the dataframes.  The `names(dats2)[i]` was an eye opener here.  it allows to use merge and let r sort on he fly.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a name for the column being appended inside the same line.  I see the default in may application is to call it *y*.  Could it be specified as *id*?