# Can I add to an existing lazy database in R without having to recreate everything?

Tags: r, database, lazy-loading

I created a database "mydb" that when run with lazyLoad("mydb") import in the workspace
the (big) data.frames X and Y. 
I created "mydb" putting X and Y in an environment `e` and using the command `tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e,"mydb")`

Now I created a third data.frame Z (quite big as well).

How can I add it to "mydb" without having to recreate the lazy objects for X and Y as well?

Comment: Possibly relevant?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757668/combine-multiple-rdata-files-containing-objects-with-the-same-name-into-one-sin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save your workspace and try adding Dataframe Z into environment and again run  **tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e,"mydb")** , please find example below

```
e=new.env(parent=emptyenv());
e$x=10;
e$y=20;
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e,"mydb");
save.image();
lazyLoad("mydb");
e$z=40;
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e,"mydb");
save.image();
lazyLoad("mydb");
```

You can see your three Data frames x,y,z.

Comment: Thanks Prateek, I actually had found your solution and forgot to add the answer!