# Names for the elements of list without change the type of them

Tags: r, list, names

I am sure this is a basic question but I can't find the right way to do this. I have a list of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. I want every element of my list to have as name its id.I tried to do

```
for (i in lenght(mylist)){
  mylist[i]=paste(mylist[[i]]@data$id)
}
#mylist is my list of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames
```

but after this I have a list of characters(IDs) and not a list of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. How can I keep my elements as SpatialPolygonsDataFrames and name them with their IDs?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073785/dataframes-in-a-list-adding-a-new-variable-with-name-of-dataframe?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you are overwriting the content of your list, and not the names of it, and in fact your list becomes a list of the IDs (converted to character, as the names of a list can be only formed by strings).

If you want to edit names of a list you can use the function `names(mylist)`, so you can try in this way:

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) { #for each element of your list
  names(mylist)[i]=mylist[[i]]@data$id #edit the names vector at position i
}
```

Moreover you don't need to use the `paste` function: you have only one single ID that you want to use as name, you don't need to paste multiple elements.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You are right about the paste function.